# Wrapping ArcGIS Map into ItemsControl (ItemsControlProxy)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I need to bind an ArcGIS `Map` from the *ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET* to a view model which provides a collection of custom models which represent the data of the individual ArcGIS `Layer`s (used for serialization purposes). Now since ArcGIS is not really MVVM friendly (most 'Controls' are just `DependencyObject`s, have no data context or don't support templating), my initial idea is to wrap the `MapView` in a *custom control* which derives from `ItemsControl` which I bind to my custom types and then select the appropriate `DataTemplate` for the type which contains an ArcGIS `Layer` that is being rendered into the map. Something like this:

```
<local:MapViewAdapter ItemsSource="{Binding MyCustomTypes}">
    <local:MapViewAdapter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ArcGISDrawLayer}">
            <GraphicsLayer GraphicsSource="{Binding LayerGraphics}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        ...
    </local:MapViewAdapter.Resources> 
</local:MapViewAdapter>
```

The `MapViewAdapter` should internally create a new `MapView` along with it's `Map` and then render the specified `DataTemplate`s into the `LayerCollection` of the `Map`.

However I have no idea how to accomplish this without re-implementing most of the ArcGIS controls. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Now since ArcGIS is not really MVVM friendly (most 'Controls' are just
>   DependencyObjects, have no data context or don't support templating)

Only UI controls have datacontext, and naturally non-UI objects like layers doesn't have templates, since that only applies to UI objects. That's just how XAML works. Instead you should think of your `Map` as you model data that you bind to your `MapView`, and not the individual layers inside the map.

You can create a IValueConverter that converts your graphics layer into a map which you then bind to you map, or even better, simple have Maps in you models.

```
<esri:MapView Map="{Binding Map}" />
```